# Joomla Stackoverflow Team

Tags: discussion

I've created a new Team (new beta feature on SO) for us Joomla users:

https://stackoverflow.com/teams/128/joomla/join?auth=749c5b06-f018-4e96-baa0-b06b0bf79dbf

Comment: hi Lodder, any idea what these teams is about?

Comment: Hi @FFrewin, This Meta post explains it all http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow ;)

Comment: Nice efforts. I hope people joins this team.

Comment: The link in the title is a deadend.  This project has been scrapped.  Perhaps kill this meta page? or is there a good reason to keep it around?